# Testing file choose and upload in Spectron

Tags: typescript, electron, webdriver-io, spectron

I have to write test for a electron GUI which contains a choose file dialog. I have no access to the implementation of the GUI.

I have wrote

```
await app.client.chooseFile('//*[@id="import-file"]/form/div/div/div[1]/input', path.join(__dirname, '..','..','..', 'Fahrtzeit.xlsx'))
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
}).getValue('//*[@id="import-file"]/form/div/div/div[1]/input').then(function (val) {

  console.log("value is :"+val);
  });
```

I get a console output

```
value is :
```

The value is empty

I am new to spectron. Am I missing something?

UPDATE:
The DOM of the choose file element is

```
<div _ngcontent-c9="" class="mat-form-field-flex"><div _ngcontent-c9="" class="mat-form-field-infix"><input _ngcontent-c9="" class="mat-input-element unit-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="fileDisplay" readonly="" type="text" ng-reflect-name="fileDisplay" title="Auftragsdatei auswählen"></div><button _ngcontent-c9="" class="btn btn-link filepicker-btn unit-filepicker"><ui-icon _ngcontent-c9="" class="filepicker-icon" iconname="a_ic_attach_file" _nghost-c5="" ng-reflect-icon-name="a_ic_attach_file" id="import-file-icon"><div _ngcontent-c5="" class="a_ic_attach_file" ng-reflect-ng-class="a_ic_attach_file"></div></ui-icon></button><div _ngcontent-c9="" class="mat-form-field-underline"></div></div>
```

Comment: Your input tag type attribute is text. Choosefile is applied only when input type is file

Answer (score 0):

```
it('Should upload a file',async ()=>{

    let toUpload = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'fixtures', 'Fahrtzeit.xlsx')

    await app.client.chooseFile('//*[@id="import-file"]/form/div/div/div[1]/input', toUpload);

    let val =await app.client.getValue('//*[@id="import-file"]/form/div/div/div[1]/input');

// Do asserts and test the **val** 
})
```

reference : http://v4.webdriver.io/api/utility/chooseFile.html

just console val and test if this works.

Comment: The same issue. The value is empty

Comment: Can you upload your input field HTML i mean this element  '//*[@id="import-file"]/form/div/div/div[1]/input'

Comment: File is getting uploaded or not.

Comment: Niether the file has been uploaded nor the text. I have added the DOM

Comment: Your input tag attribute is of type text not file. Choose file will work only for input type is file.